# Google Chrome showing square boxes on Linux

Tags: google-chrome, debian

I am using a VPS from Linode whose location is Mumbai, India. When I open `google.com` in Chrome browser then I see this weird square boxes. If I open `facebook.com` then it has the same problem i.e. showing weird font.
Strange thing is when I open `google.com` and go to the bottom of the page then it is showing my location as Beijing, China but when I open `whatismyip.com` then it is showing my location as Mumbai, India which is the correct one as per Linode.

How do I force browser to show everything in English? OS is Debian 9.

[image]

Comment: Your browser tried to show everything in English, but seems your system's default font file doesn't contain these unicode characters.

Comment: So how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Running following command fixed the issue.

`sudo apt install fonts-noto`